# Does Android 2.x support QVGA resolution?

Tags: android, android-manifest, galaxy

Based on Android doc for supporting multiple screen sizes, it seems that Android 2.x supports QVGA as small screen size. In my app's manifest file, I have

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

And

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

But recently, one customer contacted me saying that google play store says that his Samsung Galaxy Y is not compatible with my app. I looked up Galaxy Y and the only thing that makes it different from other models is that it has a small 3" QVGA (240x320) display. It is running gingerbread.

So my questions is that is there any known issues with QVGA support for Android 2.x? I also googled around and saw in some apps' release note, they specifically mentioned QVGA support which makes me think that it is not supported out of the box. Can someone confirm this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Android 2.x supports QVGA resolution displays. As a matter of fact, you can even run the latest version of Android on a QVGA display.

The jump from `small` to `normal` happens just around 3 inches and largely depends on the device manufacturer. In the case of the Galaxy Y, it's very likely that it is in fact a `small ldpi` display (QVGA).

The Android developer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) states that:

> small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

With a `ldpi` device, each dp equals 0.75 pixel - in other terms, `small` screens are at least 320 x 240 pixels. Only the `small` screens support QVGA resolution.

Comment: Thanks, Michell. I know the doc says QVGA is supported with small screen but the problem is that it does not work. I have small screen support in my manifest, but the user with Galaxy Y still get the following message: This app is incompatible with your Airtel Samsung GT-S5360. It is wired because if I login to my developer account and I can see GT-S5360 as a supported device under Samsung. Any idea?

Comment: Right, I think I know why then. Google Play has a lot of "profiles" of various handsets containing all kinds of stuff about them, including screen size. These are used to filter apps in Play. I think his phone is an operator-specific variant of the GT-S5360 and that Google Play has no profile for this specific variant. Therefore it states that it's not compatible, because it simply has no data to check if it is or not. If you send him the APK file, it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know there is operator specific devices. Yes, i sent him the APK by email.